# Online/offline tool for collection of coordinates for simulation purposes

Tags: data, tools, coordinates

Is there any good free online tool to collect coordinate positions given, say a trajectory; or a polygon. For example, retrieve all coordinates between two points, every 500 meters.

Comment: Could you clarify a bit? Two points is a line, so do you want to find all points that intersect a line? Or do you want to generate a line with vertices every 500 meters? As far as the Polygon, do you want to find all the points inside the polygon? Do you want a library?

Comment: Agree that further information is required with this one.

Comment: Right, I am working on a prototype application and trying to put together a test deck to run simulations. the collection of coordinates is taking a while and I was wondering if  there is a smarter way to do this. In other words, given a trajectory find points that belong to such trajectory ( or area) and applying some filters to this set would be nice as well. Libraries are fine as far as are well documented and easy to integrate. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try using the ArcGIS [REST Geometry Service](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/apis/rest/geometryserver.html), which gets installed by default with ArcGIS Server.

The [Densify](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/apis/rest/densify.html) method would allow you to create points along a great circle path based on some spacing.  You would provide the first an last points, or at least 3 points in the case of a polygon.

For example this [url](http://sampleserver3.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Geometry/GeometryServer/densify?sr=4326&geometries=%7B%0D%0A%22geometryType%22%20%3a%20%22esriGeometryPolyline%22,%0D%0A%22geometries%22%20%3a%20%5B%0D%0A%7B%22paths%22%20%3a%20%5B%5B%5B-98,24%5D,%5B-20,55%20%5D%5D%5D%7D%5D%7D&maxSegmentLength=200&geodesic=true&lengthUnit=9036&f=pjson) returns points every 200 km. between Longitude 98E, Latitude 24N and Longitude 20E Latitude 55N (degrees).  This [url](http://sampleserver3.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Geometry/GeometryServer/densify?sr=4326&geometries=%7B%0D%0A%22geometryType%22%20%3a%20%22esriGeometryPolyline%22,%0D%0A%22geometries%22%20%3a%20%5B%0D%0A%7B%22paths%22%20%3a%20%5B%5B%5B-98,24%5D,%5B-20,55%20%5D%5D%5D%7D%5D%7D&maxSegmentLength=200&geodesic=true&lengthUnit=9036&f=HTML) makes the same request but asks for an html formatted response instead.